# SkeetNotifier: A Tray Notifier Application for Jon Skeet's answers

Tags: app, c#, answers

#### About

A tray application for Windows that notifies you about the newest answers from Jon Skeet.
Icon approved by Jon Skeet!

#### Screenshot

[image: SkeetNotifier]

#### License

http://unlicense.org/

#### Source

http://github.com/Skomski/SkeetNotifier

#### Download

<s>http://beta.skomski.com/SkeetNotifier/publish.htm</s> (dead site)
Archived: [web.archive.org ... beta.skomski.com/SkeetNotifier/publish.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112061859/http://beta.skomski.com/SkeetNotifier/publish.htm)

#### Platform

Windows

### Contact

skeetnotifier@skomski.com

### Code

C#

Comment: I lol'd. Sadly `URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697211'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://beta.skomski.com/SkeetNotifier/SkeetNotifier.application'.`